# The most effective way to format numbers on Arduino

Tags: programming, c++, c, string

I made a big search about how to Format Numbers with the Arduino. I want to **format unsigned Longs into a String** in this format: "*23,854,972*".

The most of the snippets I found work **only with the standard C / C++ Libraries**. They **dont work on the Arduino** until I should put some STL libraries on the Arduino, which I want to prevent. It would be too bit of a overhead to import these only for this task. Also these Libraries will of course use some additional Flash and SRAM.

For my Application it is very important that the solution uses the minimum Flash, SRAM and is **fast**.

Even if a solution does not use STL or works only with the native Arduino Libraries, I would need help to decide which one is **more effective** in the sense of speed.

Incoming Number: 23854972
Arduino Program Output: 23,854,972

Comment: Have you tried writing a function that does what you're asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my try at it: The usual way to write a number in decimal is to
get the digits from right to left with a loop that looks something like

```c++
digit = '0' + val % 10;
val /= 10;
```

The following function does exactly this, with the addition of adding
commas at the correct positions:

```c++
/*
 * Format an unsigned long (32 bits) into a string in the format
 * "23,854,972".
 *
 * The provided buffer must be at least 14 bytes long. The number will
 * be right-adjusted in the buffer. Returns a pointer to the first
 * digit.
 */
char *ultoa(unsigned long val, char *s)
{
    char *p = s + 13;
    *p = '\0';
    do {
        if ((p - s) % 4 == 2)
            *--p = ',';
        *--p = '0' + val % 10;
        val /= 10;
    } while (val);
    return p;
}
```

Note that the string is right adjusted in the buffer, and the unused
characters are not touched. This means you can get a right adjusted
string by:

- pre-filling the string with spaces (for padding)
- calling the function above
- using the original buffer as the right adjusted string

Otherwise you would use the returned pointer to have a string with no
padding.

Here is a simple test program:

```c++
unsigned long vals[] = {0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 999, 1000, 0xffffffff};
const int COUNT = sizeof vals / sizeof vals[0];

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    char buffer[14];
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        unsigned long val = vals[i];
        Serial.print(val);
        Serial.write('\t');
        Serial.println(ultoa(val, buffer));
    }
}

void loop() {}
```

Answer (score 4):

> The most effective way to format numbers on Arduino

If "effective way" is minimum effort you could hack the avr-libc source code for [ltoa](https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/blob/master/avr-libc/tests/simulate/stdlib/ltoa-2.c) and do something like below:

```
char *ultos_recursive(unsigned long val, char *s, unsigned radix, int pos)
{
  int c;

  if (val >= radix)
    s = ultos_recursive(val / radix, s, radix, pos+1);
  c = val % radix;
  c += (c < 10 ? '0' : 'a' - 10);
  *s++ = c;
  if (pos % 3 == 0) *s++ = ',';
  return s;
}

char *ltos(long val, char *s, int radix)
{
  if (radix < 2 || radix > 36) {
    s[0] = 0;
  } else {
    char *p = s;
    if (radix == 10 && val < 0) {
      val = -val;
      *p++ = '-';
    }
    p = ultos_recursive(val, p, radix, 0) - 1;
    *p = 0;
  }
  return s;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  char buf[32];
  Serial.println(ltos(12345678, buf, 10));
  Serial.println(ltos(-12345678, buf, 10));
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Gives the output:

```
12,345,678
-12,345,678
```

Cheers!

PS: Please see the table driven, non-recursive, number conversion in [Cosa](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa) ([source](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/IOStream_dtoa.cpp) and [benchmark](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/tree/master/examples/Benchmarks/CosaBenchmarkUART)) for a lean and faster implementation.

Comment: How would I check which answer/solution gives the faster result? I always print delta-micros() but is there a better way?

Comment: The above solution is slow. This is a fast hack to show that you do not need all the libraries mentioned in your original question. See @EdgarBonet's answer for a solution that runs much faster. It can be improved with table lookup to avoid division/modulo. That is what the Cosa version does.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how you know if this one or the other one is faster? How to determine it?

Comment: Estimate the algorithms complexity and behavior. Read the generated assembly code and calculate the number of clock cycles. Write a test program and verify.